# Are exams during Ramadan a reason to not fast?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, school

This year Ramadan will be during the exam period for most students.

Is this an acceptable reason to not fast? Especially for nervous students who could potentially faint.

Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: With all due respect, kids these days are just too protected. The Sahaba actually went to battle in Ramadan WHILE fasting. People even up to  the last century walked kms to school while fasting and played sports if Ramadan came during summer holidays. Unless you are sick, travelling far, a minor (not crossed puberty), too old (unlikely) and it's not your first Ramadan I suggest try to fast. If you can't ,start with fasting atleast the weekends and inshallah next year make niyah to do the full month. Good luck kid. Salaam!

Answer (score 1):

only if the student is likely to faint, otherwise, i donnot think exams are good reason not to fast, back in my day, we went to school, did exams, studied during ramadhn, we fasted 13 hours, spent 10hours in school

Answer (score 1):

No , it's not a reason , only if student has a serious illness or he travels for more than 80km day of exam .

Answer (score 0):

If the person has a serious illness, and that he will get affected negatively by fasting, then he should not.

[I invite you to read this link](https://islamqa.info/en/11107), it has all the details.

Answer (score 0):

If they think they will faint, they should not fast. But in normal circumstances when examination rooms are air conditioned, I don't think skipping fast is necessary for smooth examinations. Even fasting helps with studies if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Salam, fasting for a whole month is not an easy task. There is no one who can fast a whole month without worrying about it. But that's exactly the importance of Ramadan, to show our gratitude to Allah.

If you are sure that fasting will not seriously effect your exams, then you should do it. Keep in mind that fasting has a religious plus for you, so if Allah wants, he can help you with your exams for the fact that you have fasted for him. Remember that you could feel regret later on for not having fasted this year on Ramadan.

Personally, I am going to finish highschool this summer and I am going to do the hardest and also the most important exam of my life but I am still going to fast to show my gratitude to Allah.

If your heart is willed to fast, you should do it.