# Should I Fast or not during exams/ while studying for exams?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, sawm, ramadan, school

Ramadan Mubarak
I'm a student who, in less than two weeks will be sitting exams deciding which University I get into/if I get into University. Today is the first day of Ramadan and I have not fasted, and my parents have told me it's fine as fasting can make revising and performing in exams difficult due to lack of nutrients and sleep, however, I'm still unsure on the issue. My last exam is on the day before eid so at this rate I'll have to make all my fasts up at a later date. I'm just wondering what should I do? Do I fast or not fast? Should i try 1 day and see how it goes from there? All answers are appreaciated. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are exams during Ramadan a reason to not fast?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37892/are-exams-during-ramadan-a-reason-to-not-fast)

Comment: @NanoAdam Doesn't seem like that question has any good answers.

Comment: Brother Usman, I know you are young & worried about fasting during exams. But lemme tell you what I was told when I was in school. The Sahaba fasted and fought battles, dug trenches, did zikr, helped the poor & needy. They never took fasting to be an excuse to be lazy or weak. Hence, unless you are old, sick, travelling or undergoing mensuration you should be able to fast. You might feel thirsty but with taqwa in Allah you will overcome in a couple days & fasting will be second nature to you Inshallah. Hence, in your case unless you have a medical condition that prevents you, please fast.

Answer (score 4):

Fasting is obligatory, and not fasting is a great sin.

The only people exempted from fasting are the following:

- Travelers (of long distances)
- Sick people (that are too sick to fast)
- Old people (that cannot fast)
- Those undergoing menstruation or something similar.

The point of Ramadan is not that Muslims stop working. They need to work anyway. Fearing the lack of nutrients making work harder is not a valid excuse from fasting.

It would be sinful to refrain from fasting except if a person falls into one of the exempted categories of people.

I advise you to eat food properly before and after the fast to take care of your health, study however much you are able to study, and pray to Allah to make your exams easy for you.

Comment: Does this mean I'm required to fast on the days which I am sitting the exams on as well?

Comment: @Usman Yes, it is obligatory.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I'll keep my fasts from tomorrow onwards and make up for the ones I have missed after Ramadan.

Comment: I do agree with all you are saying, but nowadays especially in fatwas of Saudi and Salafi scholars exams are to some extent considered as a hardship for which one maybe allowed not to fast.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Idk of which Saudi and Salafi scholars said that.

Comment: At least [dar-al-Ifta'/egypt](https://www.dar-alifta.org/ar/ViewFatwa.aspx?sec=fatwa&ID=12696) declared four conditions/reasons for a permission of which only 1 seems somewhat valid. [E CFR](https://www.e-cfr.org/blog/2017/05/30/%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a5%d9%81%d8%b7%d8%a7%d8%b1-%d8%b1%d9%85%d8%b6%d8%a7%d9%86-%d9%84%d9%85%d9%86-%d8%b9%d9%84%d9%8a%d9%87-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b5%d9%88%d9%85-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a8%d8%b3/) did the same giving permission based on verse 2:185. I'm still looking for my former strange findings.

Answer (score 1):

> Fast on the day of Exam

The most simplest answer would be **You are already on a Exam** , The Exam of your life. The life that you're living is Temporary and the life you'll live in your afterlife either Heaven or Hell, depends on the result of this exam! (al quran)

Now you decide, which on you'd choose, the simplest question.

And about "Ramadan", this is one of the Five Pilllar of Islam. It's obligatory (with Salah) and not performing would be A Great Sin (except those legal reasons). You should read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Pillars_of_Islam and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan

Sorry, I couldn't write it properly or in detail. And a thing, about your Parent (may allah help then to understand) preventing a Muslim (you) to perform a mandatory praying for a Wrong Reason even after knowing this, would lead them to a great Sin; and for you too, if you do so even after knowing it. "Not knowing" is another subject. In that case, after you know the right information, not letting know that to your parents, would probably leads to you another Sin. And reverse of that, you would get Sawab.

Hopefully you'll know and let your parents know the Right knowledge of Islam and perform all those mandatory prayers accordingly. Google is a great place to know everything. Just one Search, what you want to know. But you have to have that Will. Which I suppose you have.

May allah bless you all.

Comment: Thanks- I see you like one piece as well lol

Comment: Haha, nice to have you too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually fasting will help you in your exam then not fasting because your fasting even though your having hard time but you fast for the sake of allah therefore not only will allah forgive all of your sins but he will also accept your dua in iftar or while your fasting. There's saying that allah will never leave the dua of a person who fast for the sake of him. I also had a test in the 1st day of ramadan but I was happy to fast because I kinda feel protected and joyful since ramadan come only 1 time In a year it's a blessing. And I never know when I am going to die so I have to prepare myself not only for this dunya but also in afterlife because this life is only temporary while afterlife is PERMANENT AND PERMANENT. I don't want to get burn in hellfire forever and see the furious look of my lord.