# Fasting while having a quiz

Tags: sawm, ramadan

In 2 months, I should attend a test that contains 3 years of high school knowledge, and it's the hardest test we should take in our country this test decides our university/city and our academic future.

When I'm fasting, I get sleepy/headache and cant study well.

Can I skip Ramadan and fast 30 days after my test?

Its necessary to know it is not a regular test and effect massively on my future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I Fast or not during exams/ while studying for exams?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/should-i-fast-or-not-during-exams-while-studying-for-exams)

Comment: @UmH It's quite similar but it's not a regular quiz we take every semester or every month.

Comment: In 2 months ramadan will be no more. So try your best to work during ramadan and pass your exams in two months.